# Modify my Index Match to look for 'cells containing value' instead of exact match?

Tags: excel, indexing, match, contains

I have this formula that works great to pull all uc's for a given actor.

`=INDEX(uc_name, SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(actor,$A$2,0)), MATCH(ROW(actor),ROW(actor)),""), ROWS($A$4:A4)))`

But right now its only pulling results if the cell contains only 'Actor x' where some cells might actually have multiple Actors written into the cell. Anyway to modify this formula to return values whenever the actor is included in the cell?

Hoping I don't have to start over and use a different formula altogether since this is driving a bunch of other things on the workbook- I just now realized its not grabbing those 'contains' ones though.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

---

Comment: It sounds like I understood the question, but to be sure, I think you should upload a photo showing it and the desired result!

Comment: As requested! 

https://imgur.com/kk4bPmq

Comment: You have to find the matching string but first you have to get the unique from the actor, do you need unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
=INDEX(uc_name,AGGREGATE(15,7,(ROW(actor)-MIN(ROW(actor))+1)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$1,actor))),ROW($ZZ1)))
```

Or if one has the Dynamic Array Formula `FILTER()`:

```
=FILTER(uc_name,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$1,actor)))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! I used $A$2 instead, but the principle was spot on.

The dynamic array looks so easy.. lol. Someday. Thank you! This was a frustrating challenge so youre a savior

Answer (score 0):

Add a wildcard to your match:

`=INDEX(uc_name, SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&actor&"*",$A$2,0)), MATCH(ROW(actor),ROW(actor)),""), ROWS($A$4:A4)))`

Comment: So I tried this, and it still isn't picking up the cells that have the text im looking for.

I think the 'actor' its matching is the whole cell, instead of checking if the value of actor appears in the cell. I wonder if using a reference there is making it harder